# picking a word for pumping lemma for L = {a^n b^m c^n b^m a^n | m,n≥0}

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

If i have a language like $L = \{a^n b^m c^n b^m a^n \mid m,n\ge0\}$

when i pick a word for the language, would it be correct if i pick any of

these words: $w = a^k c^k$, $w = a^k b^m c^k $, $w = b^m  b^m$,   $w = b^m c^n b^m$.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! You can use LaTeX to typeset mathematics beatifully. I edited to show you how; you can click the "edited ..." link to see what I have done. We also have a [brief tutorial](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) as well as [a comprehensive reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply the pumping lemma for regular languages, you can pick any word in the language whose length is no less than the pumping length. The same applies to the pumping lemma for context-free languages.

However, some of the words in your list may not be in the language.

$a^k c^k$ is in the language if and only if $k=0$.
$a^k b^m c^k $ is in the language if and only if $k=0$ and $m$ is even.
$b^mb^m$ is always in the language.
$b^m c^n b^m$ is in the language if and only if $n=0$.

Yes, a general approach is to check the balance between different symbols. Had the language been $\{a^nc^n\mid n\ge0\}$ or $\{a^n b^m c^n b^m\mid m,n\ge0\}$, you could select $a^kc^k$ towards a contradiction. You cannot if the language is $\{a^n b^m c^n b^m a^n \mid m,n\ge0\}$, since $a^kb^k$ is not a word in the language in the first place. For that language, you can choose $a^kc^ka^k$.

Specifically, here are all the words in $\{a^n b^m c^n b^m a^n \mid m,n\ge0\}$. Note that all of them start and end with the same symbol.

$$\begin{align}
&\epsilon,\\   
&aca,\ a^2c^2a^2,\ a^3c^3a^3,\ a^4c^4a^4,\ \cdots\\
&bb,\ a^1bc^1ba^1,\ a^2bc^2ba^2,\ a^3bc^3ba^3,\ a^4bc^4ba^4, \cdots\\
&b^2b^2,\ a^1b^2c^1b^2a^1,\ a^2b^2c^2b^2a^2,\ a^3b^2c^3b^2a^3,\ a^4b^2c^4b^2a^4,\ \cdots\\
&b^3b^3,\ a^1b^3c^1b^3a^1,\ a^2b^3c^2b^3a^2,\ a^3b^3c^3b^3a^3,\ a^4b^3c^4b^3a^4,\ \cdots\\
&\vdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Apass.JackThanks for your answer, i've been told that the contradiction, by the way, is that balance between different symbols, . so if "k" is the number from the pumping lemma , and select $w=a^k c^k $ as the word to work with, and then say w=xyz where $|xy| \leq k$ , |$y| \gt 0$ . then $ y=a^j$ when i pump into the "a" part , $xyyz= a^{k+j} c^k $ that gives more a's than c's which is not in the language, which contradicts the assumption that L is regular. would this be a right approach to prove when i select that as my word

Comment: i see , what if i chose $ a^k c^k a^k$  instead . or $ a^k b^k c^k$ ? , and finally to be fully sure that the word picked is in the language , do you need to give n and m different input to generate those words ? if i ask this differently ,how would you know that a word is or not in the language?

Comment: it is ok , Could you please explain how can you determine word  $ a^k c^k b^k $  is in the language but Not $ a^k b^k c^k $  its not clear to me. or how can you check in general if the word is in the language or not.

Comment: You select any values for $m$ and $n$ and then use them. For example, selecting $m=2$ and $n=3$, you get $a^3b^2c^3b^2a^3$. Selecting $m=k$ and $n=0$, you get $a^kc^ka^k$. Selecting $m=0$ and $n=2k$, you get $b^{2k}b^{2k}$. Now, take a moment to think, how can select $m$ and $n$ so that you can get words like $a^kb^kc^k$? You cannot; unless you select $m=0$ and $n=0$, you can get $a^0b^0c^0b^0a^0$, which is $\epsilon$.

Comment: Words like $a^kb^kc^k$ end with $c$ unless $k=0$. Words like $a^n b^m c^n b^m a^n$ end with $a$ unless $n=0$. To make them the same, $k$ must be 0 and $n$ must be 0. That is, both words are the empty word.

Comment: you see in your second last comment, do you mean selecting $n=k$  and $m=0$  , you get $a^k c^k a^k$ ?? because if you say $m=k$ and $n=0$ you gonna get  $b^k b^k$ ... which i think it is another word in the language?.

Comment: My bad again. Somehow I made a typo by switching $m$ and $n$ mistakenly in parts of that comment. Of course, for $a^n b^m c^n b^m a^n$, if we set $m=k$ and $n=0$, we get $b^kb^k$.

Comment: I am going to delete all my comments here, lest they confuse future users.

Comment: No worries, you have been very helpful !! your comments and answers are highly appreciated. i am a student with learning difficulties who's trying hard to learn. sorry for being slow or asking too many question perhaps.  just one last thing , to pick a word quickly, can i make it a habit to use the same idea  $n=k  m=0$ for any language .  Many thanks again for your help and clarifications.

Comment: Well, if $m$ and $n$ appear as free variables, you can always set $m$ and $n$ to any value your want.  You can set $n=k$ and $m=3k$ together, getting many words in that language. Or you can set $n=2018k$ and $m=2019k$ together, getting many words of the form $a^{2018k}b^{2019k}c^{2018k}b^{2019k}a^{2018k}$ in that language. Or you can set $m=2s$ and $n=3t$, getting many words in that language. Or you can set $m=4$ and $n=7$, getting one word, $a^7b^4c^7b^4a^7$ in that language. You have many choices. You could try $n=k$ and $m=0$ quickly as well, of course.

Comment: That makes sense thanks a lot , in general, you can set the variables given in the language to anything you want to generate the words out of it.  i am doing this to only Pick 1 correct word  to use it in my pumping lemma proof. in that case  i thought , the easier approach for me would be to set one variable to the pumping number k  ie: n=k , and set the rest to 0,  when we have more than one variable.

Comment: "the easier approach for me would be to set one variable to the pumping number k ie: n=k , and set the rest to 0, when we have more than one variable". Down to earth. Make total sense.